# Copy-Item Failing Given Paths format is not supported

Tags: powershell, copy-item

This is driving me bananas. I am assuming I am missing something stupid, but I have tried about 10 different formats and nothing works.

This is the code I am running:

```
$today=$(Get-Date -Format o)
$destfile = "C:\SEA-FTP\toFTP\SEAInfo-$today.csv"
$srcfile = "C:\SEA-FTP\temp\QueryCSVTempMstr.csv"
Copy-Item $srcfile -Destination $destfile
```

This is the error message:

```
Copy-Item : The given path's format is not supported.
At C:\SEA-FTP\BCP_SQL_Script-v1.0.ps1:53 char:10
+ Copy-Item <<<<  $srcfile -Destination $destfile
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

I know there are a million questions with this in Google search, but it looks like I am doing what they are doing. Any thoughts on the format?

Comment: *facepalm* that was dumb. Thanks a ton. If you want create that as an answer I'll credit you.

Comment: OK, I've answered it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't put colons in a filename on Windows:

[image: Picture of Windows Explorer's tooltip error message when trying to rename a file and type a colon into the name]

Your date format is **`2016-08-22T22:15:25.3693163+01:00`** so it can't work as part of a filename.

Fix: there's no fix which keeps the name how as specified; you could `-replace ':', '-'`, any character that makes sense to you.

Comment: Thanks, I used your suggestion of `-replace` to change the ':' to a null value.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows does not allow colons (:) in a filename.**

`Get-Date -Format o` Gives you the output: "2016-08-23T07:54:19.4530323+02:00" Which does include colons.

If you want to keep the name as it is, you could replace the colon ":" with a dash. In your example:

```
$Today = Get-Date -Format o
$SrcFileName = "C:\temp\SEAInfo-$($Today.Replace(":","-")).csv"
```

**But if it was my files**, I would change the timestamp format.
The filename "SEAInfo-2016-08-23T08-33-36.3268865+02-00.csv" is just waaay to hard for my eyes to get a good understanding of when this file was created..

Depending on how detailed you need to have your timestamp, you could use:

```
$Today = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd-HHMMss.ff"
$SrcFileName = "C:\temp\SEAInfo$Today.csv"
```

Or maybe just the date will be enough?

```
$Today = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
$SrcFileName = "C:\temp\SEAInfo-$Today.csv"
```

My eyes would appreciate a filename like: "SEAInfo2016-08-23.csv"

You should try and see what you find easy to read.
Here you will find alot of examples of ways to format a Date and Time:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx